# Taking the data array in the array in JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp, getjson

How do I retrieve "bundle file" data (in the image below that I give a red circle) in the json below?
[image]

I try:

```
string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData1)
{
    JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
    string nid = groupObject["sku"].GetString();
        string title = groupObject["judul"].GetString();
        string deskripsi = groupObject["deskripsi"].GetString();
        string tanggal = groupObject["tgl"].GetString();
        string tipe = groupObject["tipe"].GetString();
        string namaTipe = groupObject["nama_tipe"].GetString();
        string gratis = groupObject["gratis"].GetString();
        string dataFile = groupObject["nfile"].GetString();
        string harga = groupObject["hrg"].GetString();
    JsonArray bundle = groupObject["bundle"].GetArray();
        foreach(JsonValue groupValue1 in bundle)
        {
        JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                 string bundleName = groupObject1["bundle_file"].GetString();
                 string pathFile = groupObject1["path_file"].GetString();
         }
}
```

but in the code `JsonArray bundle = groupObject["bundle"].GetArray();`, display an error message as shown below:

[image]

whereas "bundle_file" type is an Array.

How to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get data from json on json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651350/get-data-from-json-on-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is not an Array Value. Use ValueType property to get the type.

From the error message we can know that this is a type error. I downloaded the Json File and found out that the problem lies in the data, some "bundle"s of this Json File are of string type:
[image]

So when you call `groupObject["bundle"].GetArray()`. It went wrong.

To fix this problem, just wrap part of your codes with a if-statement like below:

```
var bundleObj = groupObject["bundle"];
if (bundleObj.ValueType == JsonValueType.Array)
{
       JsonArray bundle = bundleObj.GetArray();
       foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in bundle)
       {
           JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();
           string bundleName = groupObject1["bundle_file"].GetString();
           string pathFile = groupObject1["path_file"].GetString();
       }
}
```

And the error will be gone.

Comment: the json is like this:
idfile: "93",
judul: "JUL-AUG 2016",
sku: "2016.MHN.RH.JUL.AUG",
tipe: "0",
nama_tipe: "magazine",
gratis: "0",
hrg: "$ 0.99",
katid: "1",
nfile: "bundle.24b",
bundle: [
{
bundle_file: "bundle.24b_AUG_2016",
path_file: "http://mhndt.com/newsstand/rh/item/bundle.24b/",
pwd_file: "East#Java101."
},
{
bundle_file: "bundle.24b_JUL_2016",
path_file: "http://mhndt.com/newsstand/rh/item/bundle.24b/",
pwd_file: "East#Java101."
}
],

and in your code, what is the "bundleObj"?

Comment: sorry bundleObj is groupObject["bundle"], I updated the Answer.

Comment: For most of the data, "bundle" is an array. but some of them are empty string. For these data, "bundle" can't be convert to array.

Comment: Please help me to a problem with the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715845/error-display-json-data-on-gridview-itemclick (the problem is still relevant with this)